# Using vendor prefix for Twig Extension

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

I am trying to add my own extension to Twig.
The basic usage is working but what I want is that I can call my functions with a vendor prefix.

Example:
LinkViewHelper:

```
class LinkViewHelper extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'link' => new \Twig_Filter_Method(
                $this,
                'link',
                array('is_safe' => array('html'))
            )
        );
    }

    public function link($text, $uri, array $additionalParams = array(), array $aTagParams = array(), $external=false)
      {
            $uri = $this->uri($uri, $additionalParams, $external);
            // Some additional parsing
            return $url; // will be somehting like <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">Go to Google now!</a>
      }

    public function uri($uri, array $additionalParams = array(), $external = false)
    {
            // Some parsing goes here
            return $uri; // will be something like http://www.google.com/
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'url';
    }
}
```

Loading in my bootstrap:

```
$this->environment->addExtension(new LinkViewHelper());
```

Now I can call the function with `{{ link }}` but what I want is to call it like `{{ url.link }}`. How can I achieve this?

regards,
cefuroX

Edit:
Seriously, down voting a question because you don't understand the question isn't useful at all :)

Comment: Why not add a filter instead of a function so you can do `{url|link}` ? If you want to do `{{ url.link }}` the function link must be a function of the object url.

Comment: Because "url" is not a string but the name of ViewHelper.
And it is logically not a filter. I dont want to filter a URL I want to create an URL.

Filter is not a useful option here.

Comment: Have you tried to register your object as global as described [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals)?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, was kinda busy!
Yes I tried this already, then it works but than my function return values will be escaped (not so useful for html tags XD).
I will try to set getFunctions in combination with global. Maybe this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as I thought and mentioned in my reply to my post:
If you set your Extension as Global, you can use it with an vendor prefix.
But it will always escape your return so if you need html stuff like me you have to ECHO your return instead of returning it:

```
  public function link($text, $uri, array $additionalParams = array(), array $aTagParams = array(), $external=false)
  {
        $uri = $this->uri($uri, $additionalParams, $external);
        // Some additional parsing
        echo $url; // will be somehting like <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">Go to Google now!</a>
  }
```

In my case this is what I need but it isn't elegant at all... I will let this question open and won't mark this as the right answer because I think there have to be a more elegant way to do this.

Thnx to @Matteo to bringing me back to the global solution :)

regards,

Sebastian